# Usando javascript para criar efeito

Tags: javascript, css

Bom pessoal to querendo adicionar um efeito a uma div. Atualmente estou usando  Hover do css pra animar essa div, porém como todos sabem o hover é ativado quando o mouse passa por cima, eu queria saber como eu posso animar essa mesma div apenas quando ela for clicada.

Atualmente o código css está assim:

```
#box{width:280px; height:30px; line-height:30px; background:#0F0}
.area{width:260px; height:0px; background:#000; margin:0px 10px;  transition-duration:2s}
.box:hover .area{height:100px;}
```

Dessa forma ai a div "área" vai "crescer" ao passar o mouse por cima, só que eu quero que ela "cresça" apenas quando a div "box" for clicada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `Jquery` para realizar o efeito através de `click` e `animate`, veja:

```
$('.box').click(function(){$(this).animate({height:'100px'});});
```

Mais informações neste link http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: orion, como eu aplico esse script? Tenho que criar um nome pra esse script ai né? só que eu nao sei fazer absolutamente nada com jquery

Comment: Você vai ter que colocar no `head` da sua página uma chamada para o `Jquery` (`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. No link que eu coloquei, existe exemplos de paginas completas.

Comment: Resolveu. Certinho, do jeito que eu queria.

Comment: Só pra melhorar. Eu cliquei uma vez e a div "cresceu", agora como faço pra que a div que "cresceu" diminua caso eu clique sobre ela mesmo novamente ou em outra div que tenha a class .box

Comment: @ivanveloso você pode colocar uma condição dentro do `click` para verificar se o tamanho da `div` é 100 ou não, e com isso atribuir uma animação para cada caso, caso haja dúvidas é melhor criar uma nova questão para não fugir do tópico atual